# SQL Server CE dealing with parameter in clause of type integer

Tags: integer, sql-server-ce, in-clause

I would like to select rows, update rows or delete rows by passing the values as a parameter to operate on an IN clause. It works when dealing with string type or (varchar) type but fails when dealing integers.

```
SELECT 
    recID, recDisplayOrder, recShowItem, recAssetID, recSequence, IsSeparator 
FROM 
    tCommonAssets 
WHERE 
    recID IN (@recIDs)
```

`recID` is an integer. Passing in values like 46, 47, 48 to the parameter `@recIDs` fails because SQL Server CE sees that as a string as opposed to series of integers. Keep in mind when considering an answer that SQL Server CE does not support sub queries. SQL Server CE does not support derived tables, SQL Server CE does not support stored procedures.

I have already ready similar articles on this issue on this forum but they deal with SQL Server and not SQL Server CE.

I appreciate your time and feedback.

Comment: rather than try to make the parameters integers could you not cast recID in the where clause into a string? flip the problem round...

Comment: Hi Lefty. Using a statement like this unfortunately does not work.    SELECT        recID, recDisplayOrder, recShowItem, recAssetID, recSequence, IsSeparator
FROM            tCommonAssets
WHERE        (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), recID) IN (@recIDs))     I am really trying not to use a for each loop on each row for updates and deletes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass parameter, you must construct the SQL statement as a string in code.
You must construct/combine the SQL statement in code, so the WHERE clause becomes:

```
WHERE recID IN (46,47,48)
```

Comment: Hi Erik. If I put the values 46,47,48 into the parameter @recIDs, then sql ce perceives that as a string and not a series of integers. Hypothetically if the recID were a varchar type the passing in ('46', '47', '48'), then no problem. Its see a series of strings, but for some reason it can't parse 46, 47, 48 in a variable being passed to the SqlCeParameter. It chokes. Even when I run the query from a query window from the server explorer, it chokes. Maybe its just a limitation in SqlCe.